# Concatenated Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, concatenation

I'm trying to grab a variable and distinguish which selector should be targeted. However when concatenating the string inside the selector the code no longer works.

This works:

```
$('#step2 .selection').eq(1).click(function() {
console.log(step); // Always returns 2
}
```

This doesn't:

```
$('#step'+ step +'.selection').eq(1).click(function() {
console.log(step);
}
```

Comment: You're missing the space between the two selectors. Voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#step'+ step +'.selection').eq(1).click(function() {
                  ^
```

You're missing the space, so it's looking for a **single** element with both the ID and class. You need:

```
$('#step'+ step +' .selection').eq(1).click(function() {
                  ^
```

Comment: Ohhh dear! I'm going to kick myself for that :-) Thank you so much for helping out. That solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome. In which case, please accept the answer.